# this is my form in which all fields are post on controller page, but only one field is not post on controller page

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter-3

this is my form in which all fields are post on controller page, but only one field is not post on controller page. In this form only 'textbox1' value is not post on controller page, what is problem is their i dont understand please anyone help me to solve this problem

```
<?php  $attributes = 'id="myform"'; ?>
                    <?php echo form_open_multipart('paidcontroller/submit',$attributes); ?>

                    <div class="join-left">
                      <label>Person Name</label>
                      <input type="text" id="pname" class="required" name="pname" placeholder="anis pathan">
                       <span id="pnameerror" style="display: none;">Please enter Person Name</span>
                       <label> Mobile</label>
                       <input type="text" id="mobile" class="required" name="mobile" placeholder="9111111111">
                       <span id="mobileerror" style="display: none;">Please enter Mobile No</span>
                       <span id="validmerror" style="display: none;">Please enter valid mobile no</span>
                       <label> Email Address</label>
                       <input type="text" id="email" class="required" name="email" placeholder="@anispathan">
                       <span id="emailerror" style="display: none;">Please enter email address</span>
                       <span id="valideerror" style="display: none;">Please enter valid Email</span>
                       <label>Password</label>
                       <input type="password" id="passw" class="required" name="passw" placeholder="*********">
                       <span id="passwerror" style="display: none;">Please enter Password</span>
                       <label>Confirm Password</label>
                       <input type="password" id="cpass" class="required" name="cpass" placeholder="*********">
                       <span id="cpasserror" style="display: none;">Please enter Confirm password</span>
                       <span id="cmpasserror" style="display: none;">Password do not match with the Confirm Password</span>
                        <label>Product Category</label>
                        <?php  $attributes = 'id="cat"';
                        echo form_dropdown('cat', $cat, set_value('cat'), $attributes); ?>
                        <span id="categoryerror" style="display: none;">Please select category</span>

                       <label>Company Turnover</label>
                       <select id="turnover" class="required" name="turnover">
                                    <option value="1~50 Lacs" selected="">1~50 Lacs</option>
                                    <option value="50 Lacs~1 Crore">50 Lacs~1 Crore</option>
                                    <option value="1 Crore~5 Crores">1 Crore~5 Crores</option>
                                    <option value="5 Crores ~ 10 Crores">5 Crores ~ 10 Crores</option>
                                    <option value="10 Crores ~ 20 Crores">10 Crores ~ 20 Crores</option>
                                    <option value="20 Crores ~ 30 Crores">20 Crores ~ 30 Crores</option>
                                    <option value="30 Crores ~ 40 Crores">30 Crores ~ 40 Crores</option>
                                    <option value="40 Crores ~ 50 Crores">40 Crores ~ 50 Crores</option>
                                    <option value="50 Crores and Above">50 Crores and Above</option>
                                </select>
                       <span id="turnovererror" style="display: none;">Please select Company Turnover</span>

                                 <label>Company Logo</label>
                                 <input type="file" class="required" id="image" name="image">
                              <span id="imageerror" style="display: none;">Please select Company Logo</span>

                                <label>Upload Template</label>
                                 <input type="file" class="required" id="template" name="template">
                              <span id="temperror" style="display: none;">Please upload Template</span>      



                       </div>
                       <div class="join-right">
                       <label>Company Name</label>
                       <input type="text" id="company_name" class="required" name="company_name" pliceholder="ABC Corporation">
                          <span id="company_nameerror" style="display: none;">Please enter Company Name</span>
                       <label>Country</label>
                        <?php $attributes = 'id="country" class="required"';
                        echo form_dropdown('country', $country, set_value('country'), $attributes); ?>
                        <span id="countryerror" style="display: none;">Please select Country</span>


                        <label>state</label>
                        <?php $attributes = 'id="state" class="required"';
                        echo form_dropdown('state', $state, set_value('state'), $attributes); ?>
                        <span id="stateerror" style="display: none;">Please select state</span>


                        <label>city</label>
                        <?php $attributes = 'id="city" class="required"';
                        echo form_dropdown('city', $city, set_value('city'), $attributes); ?>
                        <span id="cityerror" style="display: none;">Please select city</span>       


                           <label>Pin/zip Code</label>
                           <input type="text" id="pin" class="required" name="pin" pliceholder="Pin/zip Code">
                          <span id="pinerror" style="display: none;">Please enter Pin code</span>
                           <label>Address</label>
                           <textarea id="address" name="address" class="required" cols="80" rows="4" wrap="virtual"></textarea>
                           <span id="addresserror" style="display: none;">Please enter address</span>

                        <label>Year of Establishment</label>
                        <select id="year" name="year" class="required">
                                <option value="2017">2017</option>
                                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                                <option value="2015">2015</option>
                                <option value="2014">2014</option>
                                <option value="2013">2013</option>
                                <option value="2012">2012</option>
                                <option value="2011">2011</option>
                                <option value="2010">2010</option>
                                <option value="2009">2009</option>
                                <option value="2008">2008</option>
                                <option value="2007">2007</option>
                                <option value="2006">2006</option>
                                <option value="2005">2005</option>
                                <option value="2004">2004</option>
                                <option value="2003">2003</option>
                                <option value="2002">2002</option>
                                <option value="2001">2001</option>
                                <option value="2000">2000</option>
                                <option value="1999">1999</option>
                                <option value="1998">1998</option>
                                <option value="1997">1997</option>
                                <option value="1996">1996</option>
                                <option value="1995">1995</option>
                                <option value="1994">1994</option>
                                <option value="1993">1993</option>
                                <option value="1992">1992</option>
                                <option value="1991">1991</option>
                                <option value="1990">1990</option>
                                <option value="1989">1989</option>
                                <option value="1988">1988</option>
                                <option value="1987">1987</option>
                                <option value="1986">1986</option>
                                <option value="1985">1985</option>
                                <option value="1984">1984</option>
                                <option value="1983">1983</option>
                                <option value="1982">1982</option>
                                <option value="1981">1981</option>
                                <option value="1980">1980</option>
                                <option value="1979">1979</option>
                                <option value="1978">1978</option>
                                <option value="1977">1977</option>
                                <option value="1976">1976</option>
                                <option value="1975">1975</option>
                                <option value="1974">1974</option>
                                <option value="1973">1973</option>
                                <option value="1972">1972</option>
                                <option value="1971">1971</option>
                                <option value="1970">1970</option>
                                <option value="1969">1969</option>
                                <option value="1968">1968</option>
                                <option value="1967">1967</option>
                                <option value="1966">1966</option>
                                <option value="1965">1965</option>
                                <option value="1964">1964</option>
                                <option value="1963">1963</option>
                                <option value="1962">1962</option>
                                <option value="1961">1961</option>
                                <option value="1960">1960</option>
                                <option value="1959">1959</option>
                                <option value="1958">1958</option>
                                <option value="1957">1957</option>
                                <option value="1956">1956</option>
                                <option value="1955">1955</option>
                                <option value="1954">1954</option>
                                <option value="1953">1953</option>
                                <option value="1952">1952</option>
                                <option value="1951">1951</option>
                                <option value="1950">1950</option>
                                <option value="1949">1949</option>
                                <option value="1948">1948</option>
                                <option value="1947">1947</option>
                                <option value="1946">1946</option>
                                <option value="1945">1945</option>
                                <option value="1944">1944</option>
                                <option value="1943">1943</option>
                                <option value="1942">1942</option>
                                <option value="1941">1941</option>
                                <option value="1940">1940</option>
                                <option value="1939">1939</option>
                                <option value="1938">1938</option>
                                <option value="1937">1937</option>
                                <option value="1936">1936</option>
                                <option value="1935">1935</option>
                                <option value="1934">1934</option>
                                <option value="1933">1933</option>
                                <option value="1932">1932</option>
                                <option value="1931">1931</option>
                                <option value="1930">1930</option>
                                <option value="1929">1929</option>
                                <option value="1928">1928</option>
                                <option value="1927">1927</option>
                                <option value="1926">1926</option>
                                <option value="1925">1925</option>
                                <option value="1924">1924</option>
                                <option value="1923">1923</option>
                                <option value="1922">1922</option>
                                <option value="1921">1921</option>
                                <option value="1920">1920</option>
                                <option value="1919">1919</option>
                                <option value="1918">1918</option>
                                <option value="1917">1917</option>
                                <option value="1916">1916</option>
                                <option value="1915">1915</option>
                                <option value="1914">1914</option>
                                <option value="1913">1913</option>
                                <option value="1912">1912</option>
                                <option value="1911">1911</option>
                                <option value="1910">1910</option>
                                <option value="1909">1909</option>
                                <option value="1908">1908</option>
                                <option value="1907">1907</option>
                                <option value="1906">1906</option>
                                <option value="1905">1905</option>
                                <option value="1904">1904</option>
                                <option value="1903">1903</option>
                                <option value="1902">1902</option>
                                <option value="1901">1901</option>
                                <option value="1900">1900</option>
                                <option value="1899">1899</option>
                                <option value="1898">1898</option>
                                <option value="1897">1897</option>
                                <option value="1896">1896</option>
                                <option value="1895">1895</option>
                                <option value="1894">1894</option>
                                <option value="1893">1893</option>
                                <option value="1892">1892</option>
                                <option value="1891">1891</option>
                                <option value="1890">1890</option>
                                <option value="1889">1889</option>
                                <option value="1888">1888</option>
                                <option value="1887">1887</option>
                                <option value="1886">1886</option>
                                <option value="1885">1885</option>
                                <option value="1884">1884</option>
                                <option value="1883">1883</option>
                                <option value="1882">1882</option>
                                <option value="1881">1881</option>
                                <option value="1880">1880</option>
                                <option value="1879">1879</option>
                                <option value="1878">1878</option>
                                <option value="1877">1877</option>
                                <option value="1876">1876</option>
                                <option value="1875">1875</option>
                                <option value="1874">1874</option>
                                <option value="1873">1873</option>
                                <option value="1872">1872</option>
                                <option value="1871">1871</option>
                                <option value="1870">1870</option>
                                <option value="1869">1869</option>
                                <option value="1868">1868</option>
                                <option value="1867">1867</option>
                                <option value="1866">1866</option>
                                <option value="1865">1865</option>
                                <option value="1864">1864</option>
                                <option value="1863">1863</option>
                                <option value="1862">1862</option>
                                <option value="1861">1861</option>
                                <option value="1860">1860</option>
                                <option value="1859">1859</option>
                                <option value="1858">1858</option>
                                <option value="1857">1857</option>
                                <option value="1856">1856</option>
                                <option value="1855">1855</option>
                                <option value="1854">1854</option>
                                <option value="1853">1853</option>
                                <option value="1852">1852</option>
                                <option value="1851">1851</option>
                                <option value="1850">1850</option>
                                <option value="1849">1849</option>
                                <option value="1848">1848</option>
                                <option value="1847">1847</option>
                                <option value="1846">1846</option>
                                <option value="1845">1845</option>
                                <option value="1844">1844</option>
                                <option value="1843">1843</option>
                                <option value="1842">1842</option>
                                <option value="1841">1841</option>
                                <option value="1840">1840</option>
                                <option value="1839">1839</option>
                                <option value="1838">1838</option>
                                <option value="1837">1837</option>
                                <option value="1836">1836</option>
                                <option value="1835">1835</option>
                                <option value="1834">1834</option>
                                <option value="1833">1833</option>
                                <option value="1832">1832</option>
                                <option value="1831">1831</option>
                                <option value="1830">1830</option>
                                <option value="1829">1829</option>
                                <option value="1828">1828</option>
                                <option value="1827">1827</option>
                                <option value="1826">1826</option>
                                <option value="1825">1825</option>
                                <option value="1824">1824</option>
                                <option value="1823">1823</option>
                                <option value="1822">1822</option>
                                <option value="1821">1821</option>
                                <option value="1820">1820</option>
                                <option value="1819">1819</option>
                                <option value="1818">1818</option>
                                <option value="1817">1817</option>
                                <option value="1816">1816</option>                                
                        </select>

                        <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
                            <label>Textbox #1 : </label>
                            <input type="text" id="textbox1" class="required">
                        </div>
                            <button type="submit" id="add" name="add" value="Submit">ADD PRODUCT</button>
                            <button type="submit" id="remove" name="remove">REMOVE</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="main-batton">                                    
                        <button type="submit" id="fill" name="fill" value="Submit">SUBMIT</button>                           
                    </div>
                    <?php form_close(); ?>
```

this input field is not post on controller page

```
<div id="TextBoxDiv1">
                            <label>Textbox #1 : </label>
                            <input type="text" id="textbox1" class="required">
                        </div>
```

this is my jquery validation code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var counter = 2;

        $("#add").click(function() {
            if (counter > 10) {
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allow");
            return false;
        }

        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);

        newTextBoxDiv.after('#TextBoxDiv').html('<label>Textbox #' + counter + ' : </label>' +
        '<input type="text" class="required" name="textbox' + counter +
        '" id="textbox' + counter + '" value="" >');

        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo(".join-right");

        $('#textbox' + counter).rules("add", {
        required: true
        })

        counter++;
    });
  $("#remove").click(function() {
    if (counter == 1) {
      alert("No more textbox to remove");
      return false;
    }

    counter--;
    $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();

  });


  $('#fill').click(function() {
    $("#myform").submit();
  });
  $.validator.addMethod("requiredCountry", function(element) {
                return ( $("#country").val() !='0' );
            }, "Please select country.");
  $.validator.addMethod("requiredState", function(element) {
                return ( $("#state").val() !='0' );
            }, "Please select State.");
  $.validator.addMethod("requiredCity", function(element) {
                return ( $("#city").val() !='0' );
            }, "Please select City.");          
  $("#myform").validate({

      rules: {
      // The key name on the left side is the name attribute
      // of an input field. Validation rules are defined
      // on the right side
      pname: "required",
      company_name: "required",
      email: {
        required: true,        
        email: true
      },
      mobile: {
        required: true

      },
      passw: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5
      },
      cpass: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        equalTo: "#passw"
      },

       country: { 
           requiredCountry : true 
       },
       state: { 
           requiredState : true 
       },
       city: { 
           requiredCity : true 
       },
       address: {
           required: true
       },
       pin: {
           required: true,
           minlength: 6
       }
    },
    // Specify validation error messages
    messages: {
      pname: "Please enter your Person Name",
      company_name: "Please enter your Company Name",
      passw: {
        required: "Please enter a password",
        minlength: "Password must be at least 5 characters"
      },
      cpass: {
        required: "Please enter a confirm password",
        minlength: "Password must be at least 5 characters",
        equalTo: "Please enter same password as above"
      },      
      mobile: {
        required: "Please enter a Mobile No"

      },
      email: {
        required: "Please enter email address",
        email: "Please enter a valid email address."
      },
      address: {
        required: "Please enter Address"        
      },
      pin: {
        required: "Please enter pin code",
        minlength: "Pin code must be six digit"
      },   
    }            
    });     
  });
</script>
```

please anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: please specify where you are having error.

Answer (score 1):

Your input field is missing the "name" attribute, so it won't be posted:

```
<div id="TextBoxDiv1">
    <label>Textbox #1 : </label>
    <input type="text" id="textbox1" name="textbox1" class="required">
</div>
```

Comment: this must be the answer